# Return any and all column headers if the cell contains "X" or a value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table which data like this

```
Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D
X     |       |       | Col A
      | X     | X     | Col B, Col C
      | X     |       | Col B
```

Col D is the result I am trying to achieve
Col D needs to output any of the column headers once any other header contains an X

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!

I will add that this is on MS Excel, and I have seen answers for this but it has been for other programs, I believe Visual Basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple IF statements should be enough if there are only a few columns

```
=IF(A2="X",A$1,"") &  IF(AND(A2="X",B2="X"),",","")  & IF(B2="X",B$1,"") &  IF(AND(B2="X",C2="X"),",","")  & IF(C2="X",C$1,"")
```